# insert method returns 1 two time in Sql Lite android

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

In my app i am adding the row in database. But the rowid is coming 1 two time earlier. What could be problem ?

```
long rowId=getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_MEDIA_DETAILS, null, contentValues);
```

Hello,

The table creation is as follow.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDIA_DETAILS + " (" + COLUMN_PROJECT_ID + " LONG," + COLUMN_MEDIA_ID + " LONG," + COLUMN_MEDIA_SEQUENCE
                + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_MEDIA_PATH + " TEXT," + COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_TITLE_STYLE + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_TITLE_TEXT + " TEXT,"
                 + COLUMN_IMAGE_DURATION + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_TRIM_LEFT + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_TRIM_RIGHT + " INTEGER,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY( " + COLUMN_PROJECT_ID + ","
                + COLUMN_MEDIA_SEQUENCE + " ));");
```

as you can see i have already primary key for the combination of two colum like project_id and column_media_sequence so i can not have another primary key in that table so i can not create another one.

Comment: `rowid is coming 1 two time earlier`, what does that suppose to mean? How would we know if you have set **PrimaryKey** and/or **AutoIncrement** attribute to that column without seeing your table creation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I managed to understand your question right -
Make sure you are adding `AUTOINCREMENT` when you create your table

for example

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE + " (" + C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                       + C_USERNAME + " text)");
```

and don't send a value of your ID column in your contentValues..

Comment: hello, the table creation is as follow                                                              db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDIA_DETAILS + " (" + COLUMN_PROJECT_ID + " LONG," + COLUMN_MEDIA_ID + " LONG," + COLUMN_MEDIA_SEQUENCE
    + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_MEDIA_PATH + " TEXT," + COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_TITLE_STYLE + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_TITLE_TEXT + " TEXT,"
     + COLUMN_IMAGE_DURATION + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_TRIM_LEFT + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_TRIM_RIGHT + " INTEGER,"
    + "PRIMARY KEY( " + COLUMN_PROJECT_ID + ","
    + COLUMN_MEDIA_SEQUENCE + " ));");

Comment: @kartiktrivedi then fix it... just read my answer again.. or read a tutorial about sqlite .. I dont know how to explain it any better and I wont change your code for you since I don't know your goal..